# $m+n = (n,m)^2; n+l = (n,l)^2; l+m = (m,l)^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Find all natural numbers $m,n,l$ such that $$m+n = (n,m)^2; \quad  n+l = (n,l)^2; \quad l+m = (m,l)^2$$

where $(a,b)$ is the greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

---

I only managed to find that if $d = (m,n,l)$ then $d=1$ or $d=2$. But I couldn't prove anything else in each of the cases.

Comment: WLOG (thanks to the symmetry), let $m$ be the largest of the three; then $\sqrt{m}\leq\gcd(m,n)\leq \sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{m}$.  This substantially constrains divisors...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I've been able to find such constrains on the gcd function, but how will that help me find the actual numbers?

Comment: Stefan: suppose that $a=\gcd(m,n)$ and $b=\gcd(m,l)$. You've shown that $\gcd(a,b)\leq 2$; OTOH, $\mathop{lcm}(a,b)\leq m$ (since they're both divisors of $m$). Now, use the formula $\gcd(a,b)\mathop{lcm}(a,b)=ab$ along with the bounds you have on the size of $a$ and $b$; you should find there are very few choices...